# Get the number of members of a discord server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

For a project, I need to export the total number of members of a Discord server list. Is there a way to get this number without accessing the server? So far I've tried something with what I've found on various forums but I get an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'memberCount')

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const token = 'MyToken';

client.login(token);

client.on('ready', async () => {
    let myGuild = await client.guilds.cache.get('798982176502054933');
    let memberCount = myGuild.memberCount;
    console.log(memberCount);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`client.guilds.cache.get('798982176502054933')` doesn't return a promise as it is a collection so you don't have to use **await** with it.

```
let myGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('798982176502054933');
let memberCount = myGuild.memberCount;
console.log(memberCount);
```

Comment: indeed, thank you. However, my memberCount is always in error

Comment: @Nosakah if you are having problems with .memberCount you can try myGuild.members.cache.size

Answer (score 0):

a better approach for this is to use the `.fetch(id)` function. this code waits for the fetch to find the guild then will console log the guild member count. if your bot cant find the server it will throw an error.

```js
client.on('ready', async () => {
    await client.guilds.fetch('798982176502054933')
    .then(myGuild => {
      console.log(myGuild.memberCount)
    })
});
```

Comment: What's with all the `async`/`await` and `then`/`catch`?

Comment: the async and await is to wait for the function to finish and the catch is to catch any errors when fetching

Comment: Yes, but `async`/`await` here is completely useless. You should not mix them with `then`s.

Comment: To clarify, async/await is the asynchronous way to handle a promise while then/catch is the synchronous way. There's no need to use both on the same promise.